# Consuming an API and displaying items in chart/Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rest, api, chart.js

I'm creating a dashboard application where i have to display statistics and data retrieved from my MongoDB into diffrent types of charts and maps using Angular and Spring boot .Thing is when trying to consume my APIs so i can display data into the charts, the data comes out empty.
Below the writer.service.ts file:

```
export class WriterService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getWritersList(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<Writer[]>('http://localhost:8088/users/getall');
  }
}
```

Here's my app.component.ts file:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  wrs:Writer[];
  title = 'Library Dashboard';
  LineChart=[];
  BarChart=[];
  PieChart=[];

  nms=[];
  bks=[];
  rds=[];

  constructor( private wrService:WriterService) {
      this.wrs=[];
  }



  ngOnInit()
  {
      this.wrService.getWritersList().subscribe(
          res=>{
          this.wrs=res;
          this.nms=res.username;
          this.bks=res.nb_published_books;
          console.log(res);
      })


     // Line chart:
this.LineChart = new Chart('lineChart', {
  type: 'line',
data: {

 labels: this.nms,
 datasets: [{
     label: 'Number of published books',

     data: this.bks,
     fill:false,
     lineTension:0.2,
     borderColor:"red",
     borderWidth: 1
 }]
}, 
options: {
 title:{
     text:"Line Chart",
     display:true
 },
 scales: {
     yAxes: [{
         ticks: {
             beginAtZero:true
         }
     }]
 }
}
});
```

In the console i get "Undefined" and the chart comes out empty, with no data displayed.

And this is the json data that i'm trying to use:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5d59b7e46b7c143594d5689b",
    "username": "titi",
    "password": "azerty",
    "first_name": "Leo",
    "last_name": "Tolstoy",
    "gender": "male",
    "age": "82",
    "country_of_origin": "Russia",
    "county_of_stay": "Albania",
    "education_level": "master degree",
    "major": "Philosophy",
    "years_of_experience": "50",
    "current_State": "Freelancer",
    "number_of_written_books": 3,
    "number_of_published_books": 2,
    "game_genre": "Action",
    "publisher_name": "HarperCollins",
    "list_of_books":[
      {"_id": "2k49b7e46b7c143594d5689b",
    "title": "War and Peace",
    "description": "War and Peace broadly focuses on Napoleon’s invasion of Russia in 1812 and follows three of the most well-known characters in literature: Pierre Bezukhov, the illegitimate son of a count who is fighting for his inheritance and yearning for spiritual fulfillment; Prince Andrei Bolkonsky, who leaves his family behind to fight in the war against Napoleon; and Natasha Rostov, the beautiful young daughter of a nobleman who intrigues both men.",
    "year_of_publication":1868,
    "category":"historical"},
    {"_id": "4m79b7e46b7c143594d5124l",
    "title": "Anna Karenina",
    "description": "Anna Karenina is the tragic story of Countess Anna Karenina, a married noblewoman and socialite, and her affair with the affluent Count Vronsky. ... Back in Russia, she is shunned, becoming further isolated and anxious, while Vronsky pursues his social life.",
    "year_of_publication":1877,
    "category":"romance"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "5d5b04da38f3b21f85a063a7",
    "username": "jojo",
    "password": "qsdfgh",
    "first_name": "Jojo",
    "last_name": "Moyes",
    "gender": "female",
    "age": "50",
    "country_of_origin": "United Kingdom",
    "county_of_stay": "Australia",
    "education_level": "master degree",
    "major": "Journalism",
    "years_of_experience": "30",
    "current_State": "Employee",
    "number_of_written_books": 30,
    "number_of_published_books": 20,
    "game_genre": "Romance",
    "publisher_name": "Graywolf Press",
    "list_of_games":[
         {"_id": "5g67b7e46b7c143594d5124l",
    "title": "Me before you",
    "description": "Louisa Clark is an ordinary girl living an exceedingly ordinary life—steady boyfriend, close family—who has barely been farther afield than their tiny village. She takes a badly needed job working for ex–Master of the Universe Will Traynor, who is wheelchair bound after an accident.",
    "year_of_publication":2012,
    "category":"romance"}
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you add the service method to the question please?

Comment: console.log(res); res is undefinded?

Comment: Open f12 console in browser and look if http://localhost:8088/users/getall returns anything

Comment: for this i get the hole json response, it's undefined when it comes to retrive fields from the list

Answer (score 1):

What I can see from your code, you're creating a chart outside of the subscribe which means, you create it when don't have any data yet. You should move that creation inside the `subscribe`.

Something like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.wrService.getWritersList().subscribe(
        res => {
            this.wrs=res;
            this.nms=res.username;
            this.bks=res.nb_published_books;
            console.log(res);

            // Line chart:
            this.LineChart = new Chart('lineChart', {
                type: 'line',
                data: {

                    labels: this.nms,
                    datasets: [{
                        label: 'Number of published books',

                        data: this.bks,
                        fill:false,
                        lineTension:0.2,
                        borderColor:"red",
                        borderWidth: 1
                    }]
                }, 
                options: {
                    title:{
                        text:"Line Chart",
                        display:true
                    },
                    scales: {
                        yAxes: [{
                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero:true
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: nothing changed

Comment: @MarTech can you create a stackblitz example with the problem?

Comment: https://angular-qbfwnq.stackblitz.io

Comment: Can you send a link to the editor, not the app itself? I can't open it

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qbfwnq

Comment: There some errors which are not described in the question. Like bad imports, missing providers etc. Can you please prepare the example properly?

Comment: it's a stackblitz issue

Comment: @MarTech dude I'm trying to help you here. You could at least take a look at those errors. Here's fixed stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nr9nwu. But there's a call to `localhost`, change it to the correct endpoint, so we get a real response

Comment: i included a json file that contains almost the same result as my WS

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
getWritersList(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<Writer[]>('http://localhost:8088/users/getall');
  }
```

to

```
getWritersList(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>('http://localhost:8088/users/getall');
  }
```

and see if it helps.

Comment: still the same issue

Comment: Can you add  console.log('the resp:',res); above of this.wrs=res;

Comment: I think its weird that you can see the data in f12 and you still dont get the data in the this.wrService.getWritersList().subscribe method. Could you please dubbelcheck if the data is in the res. Write a specific console log in the TOP off that method s. Ex: console.log("resp:",res). Above this.wrs = res. I have looked at you code in stackblitz and the service seems correct (apart from the naming thats wrong). Simplify it. Remove all aother things in this.wrService.getWritersList().subscribe(res => {. Just keep the console.log